# iOS app rejection due to email button for enquiries

Tags: iphone, ios, email, app-store, appstore-approval

Today one of our app got rejected due to email button for enquiries and info label with company name and telephone number (not clickable) . They are saying this is not compliance with paragraph 11.13.

> Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions
>   to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes to a web site
>   to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Interesting thing is they have approved our previous app with same functionality.

I feel this is a misjudgment and putting email button is compliance with Apple rules.

I do appreciate you opinion.

Comment: Are you using MFMailViewController for composing & delivering email messages? If not - that could be the issue.

Comment: paragraph 11.13. is basically saying - don't implement your own in-app purchases in your app. Which we all know. However I don't see what that has to do with an email/ info button. You should at the very least be able to get some clarification and have some grounds to appeal. Be prepared to bend to Apple's will though. Best bet I would think is to find precedent for similar techniques already on the app store and say - this technique has been approved before, where does my app's implementation differ from these?

Comment: This is what apple says for that. "On occasion, there may be apps on the App Store that don't appear to be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. We work hard to ensure that the apps on the App Store are in compliance and we try to identify any apps currently on the App Store that may not be."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's ways are mysterious and capricious. I suspect this is just an over zealous reviewer, and would be approved if you appealed (or just submitted another version with a few more changes and got a different person to check it).

However, if you want an "e-mail enquiry" system that will surely comply with their rules, why not use the `MFMailComposeViewController` to display the mail sheet in-app? There is no link to an external site then, so you cannot be accused of trying to siphon off users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am using "MFMailComposeViewController". That is why I wonder.

Comment: Then it's unlikely to be that particular issue that annoyed them - the rule is only for outright links to an external site. It could just be a mistake. If you're just display a mail composer that sends to `support@mycompany.com`, there's no issue at all. If that is *really* the problem, just write back and explain, and I'd be shocked if the rejection stood.

Comment: I do agree with Adam. I will try. Thanks

Comment: After explaining everything, bloody apple has rejected the app again, while proving same iPad app (without doing any modification). I haven't got much time to appeal against. But next time I will appeal.